# XML RPC запрос, яндекс api, ошибка авторизации

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest

API Яндекс.Услуг организовано в соответствии с принципами REST. Взаимодействие с API осуществляется по протоколу HTTP. Обращение к API осуществляется посредством GET-запросов, сервис возвращает данные в XML-формате.
Это мой запрос к сервису Яндекса.

```
$this->load->library('xmlrpc');                
$this->xmlrpc->server('http://api.uslugi.yandex.ru/1.0/banks?region=Moscow&[key=2VUk2QADAAABNEKTP58LHXUvmeBRE2pE950-2jqImmA7MA]');

$request = array();                
$this->xmlrpc->request($request);
$this->xmlrpc->set_debug(TRUE);
if ( ! $this->xmlrpc->send_request())
{
    echo $this->xmlrpc->display_error();
}
else
{
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($this->xmlrpc->display_response());
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

Выдает  такой ответ

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<error code="401" message="Unauthorized">
<request>http://api.uslugi.yandex.ru/1.0/banks?region=Moscow&**amp;**[key=2VUk2QADAAABNEKTP58LHXUvmeBRE2pE950-2jqImmA7MA]</request>
<comment>Invalid credentials</comment>
</error>
```

amp; - Не знаю откуда берется это знак... И пароль вставил, что по мылу прислали.

Каждый запрос к API состоит из следующих компонент:

- HTTP-заголовков запроса; проверяются
     значения заголовков Referer и
     Authorization, подробнее см. раздел
     Доступ к API.   Здесь похоже верно потому что key указываю
- основного URL запроса 
     http://api.uslugi.yandex.ru/1.0/;  Тоже правильно
- ресурса, например, banks/credits/search;    Верно /banks же вызываю...
- параметров GET-запроса. ... не нужны пока..не знаю что не так..

Comment: С &amp; скорее всего все впорядке, это и есть амперсант.

Comment: Мне кажется, что просто нужно прочитать внимательно [тут]( http://api.yandex.ru/uslugi/doc/banks-dg/concepts/apikey.xml#apikey).

Comment: http://mytesting.net63.net/index.php/pages/analyze
страница к которой делаю api. Ключ для домена http://mytesting.net63.net/: 2VUk2QADAAABNEKTP58LHXUvmeBRE2pE950-2jqImmA7MA

Comment: Мне кажется, здесь xmlrpc использовать не выйдет, еще можно попробовать передавать ключ без квадратных скобок.

Comment: Referer не могу..нет таких свойств..а ключ без квадратных ставил, в разных вариациях...http://api.uslugi.yandex.ru/1.0/banks ? [key=<API-ключ>] & region=<регион>
это из документации пример, по его структуре делаю, но не работает.
Как мне запрос на этот адресс делать и ответ получить?

Comment: Аналогичная проблема.

Answer (score 2):

Тут есть фундаментальная ошибка

> API Яндекс.Услуг организовано в соответствии с принципами REST.
>   Взаимодействие с API осуществляется по протоколу HTTP. Обращение к API
>   осуществляется посредством GET-запросов, сервис возвращает данные в
>   XML-формате.

А вот тут

```
$this->load->library('xmlrpc');
```

это вы очевидно пытаетесь подключить в Сodeigniter модуль xml-rpc. Xml-rpc и REST вебсервисы работают по разному. Вот тут есть краткая [информация по реализации взаимодействия с REST сервисом](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter-2/) на базе CI и [вот этой](http://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restclient) библиотеки, хотя на самом деле тут можно вообще обойтись

```
$result = simplexml_load_file("http://api.uslugi.yandex.ru/...");
```

а потом обработать получившийся результат

Comment: Если ещё кому-то будет полезно :-)

Answer (score 0):

> 401    Invalid credentials Ключ доступа не указан в запросе либо не валиден.

Я думаю, проблема все-таки с ключом...

Прочитайте внимательнее

[Банковские услуги. Руководство разработчика / Доступ к API](http://api.yandex.ru/uslugi/doc/banks-dg/concepts/apikey.xml)

Ну, и соответственно, нужно посмотреть хедеры, а конкретно - параметр реферер. Ну и в дополнение, ключ указываем без квадратных скобок.